# myclabs/deep-copy unexpected function

Tags: deep-copy

I couldn't find a clear solution online, so I am including the problem and solution here for anybody who may have a similar problem.

```
unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or \\\\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /var/www/html/basic/vendor/myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/deep_copy.php
```

deep-copy was causing the error above. It transpires this is because deep-copy >1.8.1 is incompatible with PHP v7.3 (which is what I am using).

I updated the composer.json file (forcing a downgrade of deep-copy) as follows and then ran composer update:

```
"require": {
"myclabs/deep-copy": "=1.8.0",
```

This solved the problem.

I hope somebody finds this useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved as per comments above (by downgrading deep-copy)